# creating custom UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I'm designing a checklist app.  As part of my interface, I have other elements on some scenes and therefore I cannot easily create a static UItableview array and keep my design concept in mind (there probably is a way, but as far as I can tell so far it's more complex than the alternative I've thought of...  If not, please say!!!)

Therefore, the next solution I've thought of is to create a custom UIButton for each checklist item.  I've created two images - a background for uncompleted, and a background for completed

My idea is that when the button is pressed I change a BOOL variable which using an if{} else {} method transitions between the two backgrounds.

The question I have, is instead of doing the same identical thing, multiple times for each individual step of the checklist, on multiple ViewControllers - is there a way of creating a class of custom UIButton with the same behaviour and default FALSE setting which can be called by the individual ViewControllers?

Thanks in advance
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in UIButton's `setSelected:(BOOL)>` method and for checking you can use `isSelected`..

Like if I have one UIButton named btnOrder then `[btnOreder serSelected:FALSE];` and if I have to check wether it is selected or not then

`if([btnOreder isSelected]) //it gives me bool either True or False
{
    //some code
}`

if you are creating custom class then you can write `[self setSelected:False]`

Comment: That's smashing thanks!  Works well.  I would vote you up if I could (reputation to date does not allow me to do this!).  If that's all in UIButton, then I can dispense with a lot of code and the need for a custom class.  Thanks for taking the time to answer what must be a fairly noobish question!

Comment: if you are satisfied then you can do that this answer is correct... Means mark my answer as correct....